# Part sum of a partition of a positive integer $n$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, young-tableaux

Let $\lambda = (\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_p)$ be [a partition of a positive integer $n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)). We call $\lambda_i$ a part of $\lambda$. I am interested in the sum of arbitrary parts of $\lambda$.

Whether a formula or an algorithm computes all possible sum of arbitrary parts of $\lambda$.

For example, $\lambda = (1,2,2,3)$, all possible sum of arbitrary parts is $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$.

Comment: What do you mean by partition of a positive integer? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @  Sayantan Santra Thank you very much. I have already added.

Comment: are you looking for a formula different from the Generating Function   $\prod_i{(1+ x^{\lambda_i} ) }$ ?

Comment: @  Wouter M. Thanks.  I think that I am looking  all possible partial sum of a finite set $\lambda$.